# ArrayList to repeating XML using betwixt

Tags: java, xml, betwixt

I am using Betwixt to output XML from a Java class, using .betwixt files to configure the mapping.

I am required to output some XML like this ( I have to conform to a third party DTD:

```
<data>
   <Status>Active</Status>
   <StatusCount>3</StatusCount>
   <Status>InActive</Status>
   <StatusCount>5</StatusCount>
   <Status>Banned</Status>
   <StatusCount>1</StatusCount>
</data>
```

My class has a method which returns a list of StatusCount objects

```
List<StatusCount> getStatusCounts() {
```

My StatusCount Object has:

```
String getStatusName() { ... }
String getStatusCount() { ... }
```

I can't work out the betwixt config to get the  output I want. I get an extra element wrapping each pair of Status/StatusCount nodes, which I don't want.

Is it possible not to have this element? Thanks for any help!

Answer (score 0):

I don't think that specific format is possible, i.e. you can't guarantee `Status` and `StatusCount` come one after the other.

You can, however, construct a class that binds the XML representation and your `StatusCount` object where it has two lists of `String` like:

```
public class StatusCountProxy {
    private List<String> statusName = new ArrayList<String>();
    private List<String> statusCount = new ArrayList<String>();
}
```

From these strings you can build your pairs. This should make it possible to deserialize the given xml with betwixt. For serialization to the same format you need to hack a little where you must create a `Status` object and a `StatusCount` object, then write them out in pairs.